# Timeline speed keeps increasing when I recall method

Tags: javafx

I have a timeline which moves my images along the Y coordinates of my screen, but I use the same timeline for each new wave occurence.  The problem is the speed keeps increasing at an impossible to keep up speed, is there any way I can fix this?

```
Duration movEn = new Duration(55);
    KeyFrame f = new KeyFrame(movEn, e -> moveEnemies());
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(f);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

That is the timeline code I use and it works great for the first few, but then it just gets way to fast

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. Are you stopping one timeline before starting the next?

Comment: Are you starting multiple timelines without stoping the old ones? I cannot explain this behavior in any other way...

Comment: Oh boy theres my problem, I definetely do not stop the previous timeline.  Yes I managed to just add in a boolean variable to tell the timeline when to start and when to stop.  Sorry for the lack of a complete example but you helped me regardless!